# Is it possible to find description of XToolkit?

Tags: java, solaris

I try to migrate our project from jre1.6 to jre1.7. We use uspec4j to test swing GUI on Solaris. And uspec don't work normaly with jre1.7. So, I am fixing Uspec4j and it help for some tests. But some problem's still exist and they belongs to XToolkit. I found some src:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/awt/X11/XToolkit.java#XToolkit.getScreenInsets%28java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29

but it's not enough. I don't understand how to emulate activation of XNETProtocol.
(Maybe it wount help, it's just an idea)

```
     XNETProtocol netProto = XWM.getWM().getNETProtocol();
669         if ((netProto == null) || !netProto.active())
670         {
671             return super.getScreenInsets(gc);
672         }
```

Maybe some description of XToolkid code will help me. But I can't find it by google. Maybe your know where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Toolkit_Intrinsics):

> X Toolkit Intrinsics (also known as Xt, for X toolkit) is a library
>   used in the X Window System. More precisely, it is a library that uses
>   the low-level Xlib library and provides a friendly
>   (object-oriented-looking) API to develop X11 software with graphical
>   widgets. It can be used in the C or C++ languages.

This (PDF link!) is the [XToolkit Intrinsics manual](http://www.x.org/docs/Xt/intrinsics.pdf) straight from X.org. As you will see, it's a formidable API, and I suspect anything you do with this will be non-trivial.